# Can't use Warp terminal as root user

Tags: terminal, zsh

I've recently switched to warp terminal. But when I run any form of command to become the root user on my local machine, I automatically lose the "warpiness" of my terminal. How can I make the warp terminal keep the warp color scheme and themes as the warp user. ZSH is my default shell.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://docs.warp.dev/features/subshells. But maybe the 'Warpiness' has security implications and is therefore intentionally disabled.

Answer (score 0):

One would think that you could just add the warpify string to your root .zshrc file, and it starts warp but then hangs.
printf '\eP$f{"hook": "SourcedRcFileForWarp", "value": { "shell": "zsh"}}\x9c'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).